# Want Action Sheet To Display When Tab Bar Is Selected

Tags: iphone, tabbar, uiactionsheet

I have an educational app working fine with tab bars.  One of the tabs is a test for the user.  If a user taking the test selects another tab, I would like an action sheet to display to confirm they really want to exit the test since their test results will be lost.

I can't get the action sheet to display.  I am getting syntax errors with the first three examples below.  The 4th example will compile OK but the app aborts.  I can't figure out what should go after the self.  Or possibly one of the other examples would work if I had the syntax correct.

```
    - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
NSLog(@"Tab Bar Controller reached");

UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"This will end the test.  
                              Are you sure you want to leave?"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes, 
                              cancel the test."
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];   
[actionSheet showInView:elements1AppDelegate.window];
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self];
```

Ultimately, once I get the action sheet to display, I will either proceed to the tab selected or stay in the test view depending on whether the user decides to  exit or not.  Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the method `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` should indicate that it's too late to stop the selection. Its return type `void` indicates there is not much you can do about it. Instead focus on method names that have "will" or "should" in them, and return types like `BOOL`s such as `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`. So here is some basic code that does what you want.

I don't know the actual classname of your test's view controller so I'll use `QuizController` as a classname. `QuizController` is a `UIViewController` subclass.

**QuizController.m**

```
@interface QuizController () <UITabBarControllerDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate>{
    BOOL _testInProgress;
}
@end
@implementation QuizController
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // When a tabs view controller is presented viewDidAppear: will be called so here we will set this view controller as the tabBarController delegate so we get the callback.
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
}
-(void)startQuiz{
    _testInProgress = YES;
    // Begin testing code
}
-(void)stopQuiz{
    // Score test record results
    _testInProgress = NO;
}
-(void)cancelQuiz{
    // Throw out results
    _testInProgress = NO;
}
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    if (!_testInProgress) return YES;
    // If trying to select this controller then who cares?
    if (viewController == self) return YES; // Or NO. Just don't show the sheet.
    UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"You are in the middle of a test. Are you sure you want to switch tabs?"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue Test"
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:@"Abort Test"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
    // Lets cheat and use the tag to store the index of the desired view controller.
    action.tag = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    [action showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
    return NO;
}
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.destructiveButtonIndex){
        [self cancelQuiz];
        // The above cheat pays off.
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:actionSheet.tag];
    }
}
```

**EDIT (In response to comment quoted)**

> I'm a little confused about your example. Currently, my "take test"
>   class is a UIViewController. Are you suggesting I replace that with
>   your QuizController above?

No. I am suggesting that you take this code and integrate the design pattern into your `UIViewController` subclass that handles your test. Although this is a working example (providing you supply UI to toggle the `_testInProgress` ivar.)

> Do I leave my current UITabBarController in place?

Yup.

> That is currently my appdelegate and rootController.

Huh? Your `UITabBarController` is almost certainly your `rootViewController`. But unless you have done something very odd like `AppDelegate : UITabBarController <UIApplicationDelegate>`, by the way don't do that, then it is extremely unlikely that your "appdelegate" and your `UITabBarController` are the same. Much more likely your `AppDelegate` is your `tabBarController`'s delegate.

If just setting the `tabBarController.delegate` property on appearance is bad (and it could very well be), i.e. some other object needs to be the `tabBarController`'s delegate, then you'll have to forward a message to that view controller to see if a test is in progress. For this you could actually leave almost all of the code in the example unchanged. Of course you would have to remove the `self.tabBarController.delegate = self;` in `viewDidAppear:`. And put the following in your `AppDelegate`(presuming that's the `tabBarController`'s delegate):

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    if ([tabBarController.selectedViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:)]){
        return [(NSObject <UITabBarControllerDelegate>*)tabBarController.selectedViewController tabBarController:tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:viewController];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This implementation essentially forwards the responsibility to answer the question to the view controller, provided it will answer the question.

> I check in there if the "take test" tab was selected and call an
>   initialization method in my "take test" class.

In my *opinion* the "take test" view controller should simply become selected when the user taps the tab for it. And its view should contain a button with something to the effect of 'start test' on it. But that's just my opinion.

But whatever the case is the application's knowledge of whether the user is taking a test should reside in the view controller that administers the test.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  It's 2:30 AM for me now so time to call it a night and I'll try this tomorrow.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your example.  Currently, my "take test" class is a UIViewController.  Are you suggesting I replace that with your QuizController above?

Do I leave my current UITabBarController in place?  That is currently my appdelegate and rootController.  I check in there if the "take test" tab was selected and call an initialization method in my "take test" class.

Comment: NJones - sorry for the confusion about the post.  I think your example is just what I need.  If you could help me to understand it better by answering my additional questions above that would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer with a thorough response to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I haven't worked it in yet to my code but I'm sure things will work for me if I do it correctly once I fully understand it better.  

You were right.  My UITabBarController is my rootController.  Poor choice of words on my part as I was referring to the fact that those controllers are declared in my testappdelegate.h file.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Rick Good luck. I wanted to clear S.O. up a little for you. You can up-vote any and all answers that help you. Even answers on questions you didn't ask, this shows appreciation for helpful answers and questions. But you can only accept one answer per question you ask. See the [FAQs for more info.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: I'm having a problem getting the syntax correct for the <UITabBarControllerDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate> from your QuizController example above in my current declaration for my class which is:

    @interface SymbolTest : UIViewController {
 UITextField *SymbolEntered;
 UILabel *ElementName;
 UILabel *Result;
 UILabel *Score; 
}

Comment: Never mind.  I got it to syntax correctly.  (Whether I can get it to work is another matter.)

Comment: NJones - Thanks again for that great example.  I got it fully implemented now and it is doing exactly what I wanted it to.  I was getting pretty discouraged and thought I'd just do away with an action sheet and if the test taker left the view so be it.  But now I can warn them it will end their test.  This is the first app I've ever done (as you may have gathered) and now it's just a little bit better than it was before.

Comment: @Rick Glad to hear you got it working. And I'm glad to hear that you are going to warn someone before they lose work; That's always the way to go. Few things make people more unhappy with an app than having an errant touch lose all their progress.

Answer (score 0):

```
[actionSheet showInView:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Did you try this One [Link](http://runmad.com/blog/2010/04/uitabbarcontroller-and-uiactionsheet-65-percent-less-hit-point/)

Comment: Wow.  That worked.  I don't understand why, but it did.  Thanks.

However, apparently I have it in the wrong place because it switches views to the tab I selected, then the action sheet comes up. I was thinking the action sheet would come up before switching to the other tab so that the user could say yes or no to go to the tab selected.

So I'm thinking maybe I need to put the action sheet in the view where the user is taking the test, but then how does that view catch that a tab was selected?  I didn't think that could be seen there.

Comment: for more go with the link and if your problem solve please accept the answer.